# How to set environment variables for pyspark executor in aws emr?

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr

I have an AWS EMR cluster running pyspark applications (or steps, as its called in aws emr).

I want to set environment variables for the pyspark applications, and put this into the cluster configuration (after some googling):

```
[
  {
    "Classification": "spark-defaults",
    "Properties": {
      "spark.executorEnv.MY_ENV": "some-value"
    }
  }
]
```

By the environment variable is not available in the pyspark process.

I also tried:

```
[
  {
    "Classification": "yarn-env",
    "Properties": {},
    "Configurations": [
      {
        "Classification": "export",
        "Properties": {
          "MY_ENV": "some-value",
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And then output the environment variables via:

```
print(os.environ)
```

`MY_ENV` does not show up in any case.

How do I pass environment variables to my pyspark application?

Comment: can you share how you are passing this config file to `aws emr create-cluster` or steps

Comment: @A.B I do this via terraform, where I put this configuration directly as I posted it in a json file

Comment: feel free to upvote and accept it as an answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to put this in `spark-env`.

```
[
{
   "Classification": "spark-env",
   "Properties": {},
   "Configurations": [
       {
         "Classification": "export",
         "Properties": {
             "MY_ENV": "some-value",
         }
       }
   ]
 }
]
```